# How to schedule python script that accepts arguments via input()

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I have a python 3.11 script that prompts for input() and stores the responses as vars. I have been running the script interactively within my IDE.

Something like:
[I click run for script.py]

```
Enter a date:
[I enter 2023-08-09]
Enter a geography id:
[I enter 18]
```

Now I need to be able to run from command line and schedule the script. So I need to run something like: `python script.py -2023-08-09 -18`

Should I create a new version of the script that uses arguments via sys.argv and argparse, or is there a better way to adapt my script to use input() when run interactively but also send arguments via command line when run from terminal?

Comment: Just feed these arguments to STDIN (in the simplest form - like `echo -e '2023-08-09\n18' | python script.py`, or from file `python script.py <input.txt`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best would probably be to change the script to use `argparse`. It can fall back to prompting if the are no command-line arguments.

But you can use a heredoc to feed input to the script. Put this in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

python script.py <<EOF
2023-08-09
18
EOF
```

and use `cron` or `at` to schedule the script.